# Angular UI Multi Select Dropdown(ivh-treeview) Auto close Event Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, treeview

I have a multi select dropdown with dropdown auto-close="outsideClick". It's not working only when I am clicking on date picker .

**HTML**

```
   <div class="btn-group dropdown one custom-dropdown" dropdown auto-close="outsideClick"> //code inside </div>

    <div class="input-group custom-datepicker">//code</div>
```

it looks something like this.

[image]

so how can I make it work?

Comment: Please add plunk or somewhat to you question, i was able to close dropdown in [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pCcagYOcxOu3Szisdc9d?p=preview)

Comment: How is this related to Angular2?

Comment: that was by mistake selection , updated thanks.